# newline not coming in mail body in Notes

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am new to Notes.
I am trying to send a mail from my application using Lotus Notes with an attachment,mail goes properly and attachment also goes but the problem is with the body content,the body looses its format and comes in a straight line

i expect as follows

```
Dear Sir,
please check the attachment.


Regards,
NewConcept Infotech Pvt.Ltd.,
```

but it comes like this

```
Dear Sir,please check the attachment.Regards,NewConcept Infotech Pvt.Ltd.,
```

i tried everything googled a lot but no use.

this is my code

```
 public bool Email(string dbDirectory, string DataBase_Name, string Initialize_Pwd, string From, string To, string CC, string Bcc, string Subject, string body, string FileName, string LogFilePath)
        {
            bool msg = false;
            dynamic EMailReplyTo = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EMailReplyTo"];
            NotesSession objNotesSession = new NotesSession();
            NotesDatabase ndb = null;
            NotesDocument ndoc = null;
            NotesDbDirectory ndbD = null;
            NotesStream LNStream;
            NotesMIMEEntity LNBody;
            object objAttach;
            try
            {
                ////--------------------Lotus Notes Connectivity-------------------------///
                List<string> lstOutPutEmail = new List<string>();
                lstOutPutEmail.Add(DataBase_Name);
                lstOutPutEmail.Add(Initialize_Pwd);

                objNotesSession.Initialize(lstOutPutEmail[1].ToString());
                ////  objNotesSession object Initialized

                ndbD = objNotesSession.GetDbDirectory(dbDirectory);

                ndb = objNotesSession.GetDatabase(dbDirectory, DataBase_Name, false);

                //If the database is not already open then open it.
                if (!ndb.IsOpen)
                {
                    ndb.Open();
                }

                if (ndb != null)
                {
                    ndoc = ndb.CreateDocument();
                    LNStream = objNotesSession.CreateStream();
                    LNBody = ndoc.CreateMIMEEntity();
                    //   ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendBy", From);
                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("From", From);
                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal", From);
                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", To.Split(','));
                    if (CC != null)
                    {
                        if (CC != "")
                        {
                            ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("CopyTo", CC.Split(','));
                        }
                    }
                    if (Bcc != null)
                    {
                        if (Bcc != "")
                        {
                            ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo", Bcc.Split(','));
                        }
                    }
                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", Subject);
                    //

                    NotesRichTextItem objMailRTF = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");



                    ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", body);



                    ndoc.SaveMessageOnSend = true;
                    if (FileName != "")
                    {
                        objAttach = objMailRTF.EmbedObject(Domino.EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", FileName, "Attachment");
                    }
                    ndoc.Send(false);
                    ndbD = null;
                    objNotesSession = null;
                    ndb = null;
                    ndoc = null;
                    gl.runLogfile("Mail Send Successfuly To : " + To, LogFilePath);
                }
                msg = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error On sending Mail To : " + To);
                gl.runLogfile("Error On sending Mail To : " + To, LogFilePath);
                gl.runLogfile(ex.Message, LogFilePath);
                msg = false;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
            return msg;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 0. MIME

If you are using MIME then you don't need to create the `Body` field. But you need to use `<br>` instead of `newline` characters.

```
//Remove this from your code:
//NotesRichTextItem objMailRTF = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
//ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", body);

objNotesSession.ConvertMIME = false;

LNStream.WriteText(body.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>"));
LNBody.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", 1728);                

ndoc.SaveMessageOnSend = true;                

if (FileName != "")
{
    //objAttach = objMailRTF.EmbedObject(Domino.EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", FileName, "Attachment");

    var child = LNBody.CreateChildEntity();
    var header = child.CreateHeader("Content-Disposition");
    header.SetHeaderValAndParams(string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\""), Path.GetFileName(FileName)); 

    LNStream = objNotesSession.CreateStream();
    LNStream.Open(FileName, "binary");
    child.SetContentFromBytes(LNStream, "application/octet-stream", 1730);
    child.EncodeContent(1727);

    ndoc.CloseMIMEEntities(True, "Body");
}
```

### 1. No MIME

If you don't want to use MIME then you must use `AppendText` method instead of `ReplaceItemValue` method:

```
NotesRichTextItem objMailRTF = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
//ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", body);
objMailRTF.AppendText(body);

ndoc.SaveMessageOnSend = true;
if (FileName != "")
{
    objMailRTF = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment");
    objAttach = objMailRTF.EmbedObject(Domino.EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", FileName, "Attachment");
}
```

Comment: it is working but attatchbment is coming in body part and not seperately like it usually comes attatched with the mails

Answer (score 5):

Use RichTextItem's method [AddNewLine()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ADDNEWLINE_METHOD.html) do add new lines to your Body field

```
NotesRichTextItem objMailRTF = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body");
objMailRTF.AppendText("Dear Sir,");
objMailRTF.AddNewLine(1);
objMailRTF.AppendText("please check the attachment.");
objMailRTF.AddNewLine(2);
...
```

Delete the code line `ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", body);` as it won't work otherwise.

Comment: i replaced that with   objMailRTF.AppendText(body)now format is looking as desired but attachment is coming in body part only

Comment: If you want attachments not part of Body field then create another RichTextItem e.g. "Attachments" and add attachments there: `NotesRichTextItem objMailAtt = ndoc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachments"); .....   objAttach = objMailAtt.EmbedObject(Domino.EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", FileName, "Attachment"); .....`

Comment: thanks for ur great effort i got the solution n ur post helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

In your ndoc.body, you have to code the newlines as "chr$(13)chr$(10)". In java (char)13(char)10 or \r\n.

You need to replace in the String body, you get in parameter, all occurence of newline (probably '\n' but look how it is coded in the String) to (char)13(char)10.

try:

```
body = body.replaceAll("\n", "\r\n");
ndoc.ReplaceItemValue("Body", body);
```

try will \\ if it doesn't work with 1 \ only.

Comment: in my body string newline are coming in c# form because of \n\r,but in notes mail it is not working

Comment: Dear Sir,chr$(13)chr$(10)chr$(13)chr$(10)Pls. find below the attached report of vendor balance as per our records.chr$(13)chr$(10)chr$(13)chr$(10)chr$(13)chr$(10)chr$(13)chr$(10)M J Italiachr$(13)chr$(10)Manager - Shipping Accounts chr$(13)chr$(10)The Great Eastern Shipping Co. Ltd.,chr$(13)chr$(10)Palton House, 2174/A, Dr. V.U. Roadchr$(13)chr$(10)Cotton Green, Mumbai 400 008.chr$(13)chr$(10)chr$(13)chr$(10)------Auto generated report.like this it is coming after replacing