# AX 2009 attacments inside Lotus Notes richtext

Tags: .net, api, lotus-notes, axapta, x++

It is possible using AX 2009 to create email body in Lotus Notes and attach pdf or xls files inside email in needed place providing text for each attached file, and make this embedded objects clickable and possibility to rename them?

[image]

Comment: Are your email parameters under Administration->Setup->Email Parameters set up?

Comment: Yes I think, I don't know what you mean

Comment: You have to use Notes/Domino APIs. It appears that you're talking about .NET-based product and, I'm not sure whether the standard (i.e., free) Domino interop classes for .NET can get you the precise control of inline positioning of attachments that you want. In Notes mail, the attachment and the icon representing it in the rich text body are actually separate entities, and the standard API classes have limited abilities with rich text. The Notes C API has the capabilities, but it is extremely complex. A third party API called MIDAS from a company called Genii Software is simpler, but not free.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: This is obviously not a complete guide to using the Notes interop classes from .NET, but take a look at the code in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124953/newline-not-coming-in-mail-body-in-notes
And look at the first two answers. This will give you the key class and method names, and if you search on those terms with "C#" you will probably find some additional examples.

Answer (score 3):

Try this job as a test with your file...

```
static void TestEmails(Args _args)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage             mailMessage;
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment              attachment;
    System.Net.Mail.AttachmentCollection    attachementCollection;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient              smtpClient;
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress             emailfrom;
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress             emailto;
    str                                     messageBody;
    str                                     Subject;
    str                                     SMTPServer;
    str                                     Filenm;
    FileIOPermission                        permission1;

    str fileToSend;
    ;

    fileToSend = "P:\\Tests\\TestFile.pdf";

    emailfrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("From@address.com","");
    emailTo = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("To@address.com","");

    messageBody = "Test Body";
    Subject = "Test Subject";
    SMTPServer = SysEmailParameters::find(false).SMTPRelayServerName;

    mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(emailfrom, emailTo);

    mailmessage.set_Subject(Subject);
    mailmessage.set_Body(messageBody);

    attachementCollection = mailMessage.get_Attachments();
    Filenm = fileToSend;
    permission1= new FileIOPermission(Filenm,'w');
    permission1.assert();

    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Filenm);
    attachementCollection.Add(attachment);

    smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(SMTPServer);
    smtpClient.Send(mailmessage);

    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly this code I have and it do not add files inside email as object but only attach file to email, I need have clickable file inside email body

Comment: Curious... why do they have to be in the body? Are these emails for internal use only? Maybe you can send a link to the file.

Comment: No I need exactly like on picture, as I need Custom Sorting of attachments, as when attachments goes outside body they sorting as they wants but not like I need

Answer (score 1):

There is no way standard AX will do that for you.

You may be able to code it, but it [looks tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/922901/4509).